# How to filter features in a tables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table for products by suppliers with which features each product has as shown in the image;

[image]

I wanted to create a Slicer from the table to act as a filter to so one slicer with Feature 1,2,3,4,5 as options in it that I can select. But when I create a Slicer all I get is 5 Slicers with the features as the heading and v (tick) as the only option.

Is there a way with Slicers or other similar method, not normal filters, where I can have a list of the features and select ones I am interested in and have it filter the table.

Comment: I don't think it's a viable requirement. Any filtering shows content based on data already in the current workbook structure. Depending on your data structure, it is recommended that you not filter according to feature but according to supplier or product

Comment: Excel creates Slicers for the columns and in your Table each slicer is column, that's the reason it create Slicer for each Feature ! But I got one possibility that U need to create one extra column at last named it Features and replace all Vs  with numbers like for `Supplier 1`,,, 1 , 2, 3 , 5 and for others. now create Slicer for the NEW Column you get buttons like `1, 2, 3, 5`. Finally for neatness you may hide the NEW Column ☺

Comment: @RajeshS I didn't quite understand your suggestion can you explain it a bit more. I create a new column with 1,2,3,4,5 but how does that filter the features?

Comment: @Naz,, here it will be a lengthy [let discuss in Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108911/all-about-slicers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to approach this:

First, I created a query (Data>Get & Transform>From Table/Range) based on the original data. I selected the 5 feature columns, right-clicked and chose "Replace values", then configured the dialog to replace the Vs with 1s:

[image]

After doing that, I converted the data type for those columns to Whole Number (the reason for this will become clear later).

Next, I closed and loaded that query into the workbook.

Then, I created a new query on the original data, but this time called it data_stacked and used Transform>Unpivot selected columns on the 5 feature columns, like this:

[image]

I then removed the Value column because it's not really of any use. Then I loaded that query into the workbook.

So now I have two queries in the workbook:

1. orig_data
2. data_stacked

Next I used Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Merge and configured it like this:

[image]

After selecting OK on the Merge, I expanded the 'orig_data' column and just included the Feature columns (which are numeric):

[image]

I then loaded this Merge query into the workbook and created a pivot table on it. I configured the pivot table to have Supplier, Product and Cost on Rows, then 5 Value fields - one for each numeric Feature column, whose aggregate was set to Average. I renamed the Feature measures to their original column names (i.e. Feature 1 through 5) then inserted a slicer on the "Attribute" field.

The net result is you are able to slice by feature name, but also retain the full row of the original table and see what other features are included in the filtered products:

[image]

The reason I went the long way round with the Merge was because I felt it was probably useful to be able to see all the features of the filtered product(s) even if you only selected one of them. Using a pivot table with the cost on the row axis avoids duplication of the cost field.

Comment: It's good idea but it involves Power Query,,, and most of the users are not confident enough, handling PQ.

Comment: I wouldn't make such an assumption about "most users". Regardless, OP has raised several questions in the past showing they are at least somewhat familiar with topics such as VBA. This proposed solution is point and click and I would argue simpler than coding or editing a macro.

Comment: Hi @Owen ,, you worked hard and deserves Up vote ☺,, I do hope OP will also try this,,, Power Query & BI are still bit complicated even though are good enough,, the DAX part especially !

Comment: Thanks @RajeshS. Agreed, they are not as accessible to many. DAX can get particularly complicated and I've found the language used in the documentation to be abstruse. Very powerful, but it requires work!